# sudo heredoc: bash: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF...EOF')

Tags: bash, sudo, heredoc

My goal is use `sudo` to write content to another user's `xstartup` file.

But my attempt...

```
sudo -iu user1 bash -lic 'cat > ~/.vnc/xstartup <<\EOF
...
EOF'
```

...results in...

```
bash: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF...EOF')
```

Yet nested heredocs works...

```sh
sudo -iu user1 bash -s <<\OUTER
cat > ~/.vnc/xstartup <<\EOF
...
EOF
OUTER
```

Any suggestions to accomplish a sudo redirection without nested heredocs?

Comment: Using the `-i` argument to `sudo` here is telling `sudo` to start an *additional* shell, above and beyond the one you're invoking with the explicit `bash -lic` later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of unnecessary layers.

```
sudo -u user1 tee ~user1/.vnc/xstartup > /dev/null <<\EOF
...
EOF
```

Comment: That is definitely cleaner, but on my system (Ubuntu 18.04), it results in `tee: /home/sudouser/.vnc/xstartup: Permission denied`. Also, I'd like `~` to resolve to `/home/user1` rather than `/home/sudouser`.

Comment: @mellow-yellow, `~user1` *does* resolve to `/home/user1`, even when evaluated by `sudouser`. Are you certain you're running this exactly as chepner provided it (with the target username immediately after the `~`)?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my side. I didn't know you could prefix paths with `~` for users besides the current `$(id -u)` one. It works great! Thank you!